# Named_scope in rails unique records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

Is it possible to have `named_scope` return records unique for a certain column?

e.g

```
named_scope :unique_styles, :order =>"title desc", :limit => 3
```

That will give me three styles but what if I want to make sure the title is different? In this case there may be three records with the same style, I want this named_scope to only give unique values of title.

So `["style 1", "style 1", "style 1"]` isn't possible, it'll force itself to give `["style 1", "some style 2", "maybe another 3"]`

- i think `group` may do it and I'm using that for now. If anyone has any comments regardless that'd be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want to explore the :group option for finders and named_scopes:

```
named_scope :unique_styles, :order => "title desc", :limit => 3, :group => "title"
```

Comment: It's ":group" not ":group_by" figured this out and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 3 peeps you can do it daisy-chain style:

```
scope :unique_styles, order("title DESC")
                      .select("DISTINCT title")
                      .limit(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If really all you want is the titles, this oughta do it for MySQL. (I haven't looked into whether other engines support DISTINCT.)

```
named_scope :unique_styles, :select => 'DISTINCT title', :order => 'title desc', :limit => 3
```